# Обращение к каждому третьему элементу

Tags: javascript

Как обратиться к каждому третьему элементу массива?

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

function func(arr) {
  // code
}

console.log(func(arr)); // [3,6,8];
```

Comment: А ваши какие мысли?

Comment: Стоит отметить, что 8 не относится к каждому третьему элементу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

function func(arr) {
    return arr.filter((el,i) => (i+1)%3 === 0);
}

console.log(func(arr)); // [3,6,8]; Здесь 8 не должен быть включен!!!
```